# Pointers and foreign keys in SQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I understand how the relationship between two tables is made using primary and foreign keys, but I just read in a textbook that two tables can relate with each other through `pointers` and `value-based reference`, `value-based reference` is clear (when value is always present and unique in the target column, a simple `==` can reference every row in the target table) but I can't find anything about `pointers` in SQL, can someone explain it to me? I should mention that the textbook also mentions this about `pointers`:

> - Pointers point to address of object.
> - Pointers are dereferenced.

thank you

Comment: They might want to say you do not need a ```FOREIGN KEY``` to reference something. But anyways, usually you should use it because the DB will take care of it and you cannot have "pointers" to non-existing rows. But idk what exactly they meant

Comment: I think your are confusing a relational database with the code that is used to access the database. Pointers is a coding concept, foreign keys is a database one.

Comment: Please cite the textbook reference. Your question is not clear, and it seems you may have misinterpreted the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book you are reading may be dealing with [the conceptual difficulties of object-relational mappers](http://blogs.tedneward.com/post/the-vietnam-of-computer-science/).

ORMs try to map an object-oriented world with pointers to objects to a relational world with foreign keys.

There are no pointers in a relational database.